# Highlight Rows in a List based on Workflow status field

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, cewp

Actually I got a code which works really nice when I use it in a list depending on a normal field. When I try to Highlight the rows considering the Workflow Status it doesn´t work, Any advises? I paste the code I have right now.

I already tried to Name the Workflow "Status" but it still doesn´t work.

Thanks in regard.

```
OnPostRender: function(ctx) {

   var statusColors =  {
      'In Progress' : '#FFF1AD',  
      'Approved' : '#FFD800',
      'Rejected' : '#01DF3A' 
   };

   var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
   for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
   {
      var status = rows[i]["Status"];
      var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
      var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
      row.style.backgroundColor = statusColors[status];
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please try to access "_ModerationStatus" field instead of "Status" field.

Comment: If that doesn't work (could be some Microsoft magic with that Field, as it also is not available in Calculated Columns) You can do it the oldfashioned way..Your code already has the ``rowId``, so you can walk the DOM TR tow to get the TD where WorkflowStatus is displayed, get the innerText and take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Found a blogpost that does exactly what you need. Changed it and added it to reflect your code.

Changed `In Progress` to `Pending` as that's what SharePoint call it while waiting for an approval/reject.

[SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Views](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/620110/sharepoint-client-side-rendering-list-views)

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
    var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
    for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    {
      var isApproved = rows[i]["_ModerationStatus"] == "Approved";
      if (isApproved)
      {
        var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
        var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
        tr.style.backgroundColor = "#FFD800";
      }
      var isPending = rows[i]["_ModerationStatus"] == "Pending";
      if (isPending)
      {
        var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
        var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
        tr.style.backgroundColor = "#FFF1AD";
      }
      var isRejected = rows[i]["_ModerationStatus"] == "Rejected";
      if (isRejected)
      {
        var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
        var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
        tr.style.backgroundColor = "#01DF3A";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Gives me this result.

[image]

Comment: Sadly it doesn´t work. I think that somehow the Code is not reaching the values with a Workflow status field in the same way it does it with a normal field.

Comment: Is your workflow status column named status? Try "_ModerationStatus" instead of "Status". See if you got better luck with that field. It might be that the workflow column got an internal name that you need to use. The value stored in the status column is a lookup as well, so use F12 developer tool and see if you can see how the value is stored. Should be ID;#Status

Comment: @JorgeNitales I think that Dikesh Ghandi got the right answer before i did. :)

Comment: As Dikesh Ghandi said I tried with "_ModerationStatus". I tried with both values (Status and Value). Also I found the ID as "WorkflowInstanceID" in the Developer tool, which looks like the internal ID but it doesn´t work either. I really missed SharePoint!

Comment: @JorgeNitales Think it should work now.

Comment: Actually it looks it works in every SharePoint but mine, so I guess there has to be a problem either with my code, or probably with some Access permissions to the "internal characteristics". Anyway, I will go on trying, thanks for your time!

Comment: @JorgeNitales just a thought, but if you compare the beginning and the end of my example compared to you, it looks like you are missing some important parts!

Comment: Actually I have it like you (For the last attemps I even copied it). I just copied the "important" part of the code where the Status is ;-)

Comment: And yet it still did not work?

Comment: You should be able to use F12 and reload the page where list/code is and see if you get any error

Comment: Hmmmm... I just checked and there is no error at all, I think I am gonna leave that for a future design of the Project...